# How to copy multiple urls hidden under texts, by selection in webpages?

Tags: websites, url

I would like to copy urls in a webpage, which are hidden under some texts.

For example the urls under the titles in the table of contents in http://download.racket-lang.org/releases/6.4/doc/guide/.

How can I do that in Ubuntu and maybe some web browsers? ( I am using firefox, and sometime google chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Right click the link and choose "copy link address". <-- That's what it is on Chrome and IE, I'd expect it to be similar for FF.